# Package a structure of HTML files in a single archive (equivalent to JAR)

Tags: html

Is it possible or is there a tool that makes it possible to bundle a structure or HTML files (e.g. javadoc) in a single arhive (like a zip or jar) and then browse them locally like a file, without HTTP?  I would like to use a solution like this to put together pretty documents with formatting and all like it would normally be done in MS Word but don't want to use Word and want to have an automatically read single file, i.e. not have to extract a zip with a file structure inside.

Comment: You could use any compression algorithm you want. If you keep the structure consistent and use relative urls you should be good to go.

Comment: You might look into pharing if using PHP: http://php.net/manual/en/intro.phar.php

Comment: actually, just plain HTML -- but thanks @jchapa